# java.lang.StackOverflowError when running cucumber under jRuby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, jruby, bundler

I have following problem with using cucumber and jRuby under windows:

```
load error: bundler/definition -- java.lang.StackOverflowError: null (LoadError)
```

It happens even on 'clear' rails project, before running any of my features.

I am using `jruby 1.6.6 (ruby-1.8.7-p357) (2012-01-30 5673572)` and this is my `bundle list` https://gist.github.com/2bc58e136cb982fc9bae

Here is the full stack trace:

```
Using the default profile...
load error: bundler/definition -- java.lang.StackOverflowError: null (LoadError)
c:/jruby-1.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler.rb:138:in `definition'
c:/jruby-1.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler.rb:126:in `load'
c:/jruby-1.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler.rb:110:in `setup'
c:/jruby-1.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `(root)'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027:in `require'
c:/jruby-1.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `require'
c:/jruby-1.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
c:/jruby-1.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/setup.rb:6:in `(root)'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027:in `require'
c:/jruby-1.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
D:/users/tgieniusz/workspace/rails/config/boot.rb:1:in `(root)'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027:in `require'
c:/jruby-1.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
D:/users/tgieniusz/workspace/rails/config/application.rb:2:in `(root)'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027:in `require'
c:/jruby-1.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
D:/users/tgieniusz/workspace/rails/config/environment.rb:7:in `(root)'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027:in `require'
c:/jruby-1.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `require'
c:/jruby-1.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
c:/jruby-1.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-rails-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/rails.rb:7:in `(root)'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1052:in `load'
D:/users/tgieniusz/workspace/rails/features/support/env.rb:129:in `load_code_file'
c:/jruby-1.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.1.4/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:171:in `load_file'
c:/jruby-1.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.1.4/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in `load_files!'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1614:in `each'
c:/jruby-1.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.1.4/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `load_files!'
c:/jruby-1.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.1.4/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:174:in `load_step_definitions'
c:/jruby-1.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.1.4/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:40:in `run!'
c:/jruby-1.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.1.4/bin/../lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:43:in `execute!'
c:/jruby-1.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.1.4/bin/../lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:20:in `execute'
c:/jruby-1.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.1.4/bin/cucumber:14:in `(root)'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1052:in `load'
C:\jruby-1.6.6\lib\ruby\gems\1.8\bin\cucumber:19:in `(root)'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug exists in JRuby 1.6.6

[Here's a quickfix](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-6400?focusedCommentId=290430&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-290430), rather a workaround than fixing the actual cause of the bug.

Cucumber guys are already aware of this and are preparing fix.

Comment: Thanks, this workaround works.
I can't wait to see this cucumber fix ;]